# Cannot find module 'D:\@craco\craco\bin\craco.js', React, Craco

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**ERROR**: I ran npm start and i get the error below:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\@craco\craco\bin\craco.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

And even you can check the package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I just changed the folder location to another folder and then today when I ran it gave this error

Yesterday it was working fine

**TRIES**

Re-Install Craco, No Luck

Re-Install React, No Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error mostly shows up when the system can not find a folder/module. As you said you changed a folder location, so most probably deleting your `node_modules` folder and reinstalling the packages will solve the issue. (P.S you may need to open the terminal as adminstrator(windows) or superuser(linux and mac : use -sudo keyword)

1. Delete your `node_modules` folder
2. Reinstall all packages(`npm install`).

**Edit:

Maybe you hardcoded this folder in one of your files. If this is not the case, start a new project in another folder. Naming the folder Learn Earn & Fun is not a good practice as it includes an '&' and space characters. You can create a new folder LearnEarnAndFun then start a new project in it. Copy the code from your old project by carefully checking

Comment: I tried that as well, It didn't work

Comment: If you are using bash make sure that when you `cd` into a directory, directory name must exactly match. E.G. your destionations folder is `d:\@craco\craco\bin`. If you `cd` into `D:\@craco\craco\bin` you may get this error. Same happened with me. Watch out upperCase and lowerCase

Comment: @Hridaya Agrawal Let me know if this solves the issue. If not I can collborate

Comment: Nopes I aren't using bash, I am using PowerShell and my location of the project is: D:/Learn Earn & Fun/learn-earn-fun so I don't think that the issue is that, And I suspect the the issue is in Node Modules, Because it thinks craco module is in D: but it is in D:/Learn Earn & Fun/learn-earn-fun/node-modules/@craco/craco/bin

Comment: I didn't rename any folder, I just changed the project into the folder Learn Earn & Fun

Comment: Maybe you hardcoded this folder in one of  your files. If this is not the case, start a new project in another folder. Naming the folder `Learn Earn & Fun` is not a good practice as it includes space characters. You can create a new folder `LearnEarnAndFun` then start a new project in it. Copy the code from your old project by carefully checking